# How does AngularJS find and load modules

Tags: angularjs

I m trying to understand the sample AngularJS app shipped with Packpub's book. the `app.js` file is defined under `client/src/app` folder and it's module definition looks like

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'projectsinfo',
  'dashboard',
  'projects',
  'admin',
  'services.breadcrumbs',
  'services.i18nNotifications',
  'services.httpRequestTracker',
  'security',
  'directives.crud',
  'templates.app',
  'templates.common']);
```

My question is how `AngularJs` will find these modules and uses in app?

Comment: No idea what the app is, but all the non-angular components listed have to be located in files that are loaded when the app runs.

Comment: @Shomz, app is the name of the module and all the stuff in square brackets are dependencies. user160820 was asking how the dependencies are loaded.

Comment: @Abhi No, no, I meant I had no idea what is that *sample app from the book* that the OP mentioned. :) And I did answer how the other modules/dependencies are loaded - by loading the files they are located in, like Anzeo answered.

Comment: Oh sorry I misinterpreted, my bad!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those modules need to be loaded in your browser as well. AngularJS does not provide a module loader such as RequireJS.

You can either add `<script>` tags in the index file or concatenate all your sources into one big file. Some of the modules can be from AngularJS (such as the `ngRoute`). These will always be available in Angular, you do not need to load the sources in separately.